# SBT: How to use `fastOptJS::webpack` in `build.sbt`?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, scalajs-bundler, scalably-typed

I have in my `build.sbt` a copy task, like:

```
copyTask := {
  val r = (Compile / fastOptJS).value
  val destinationPath = file("docs/_includes/scala-js-tutorial-fastopt.js").toPath
  java.nio.file.Files.copy(r.data.toPath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
}
```

The idea is to run `~copyTask` so the changes are automatically in my HTML page.

That works until I used the `ScalaJSBundlerPlugin`.

Now the task is `fastOptJS::webpack`.

The question is how to adjust my copy task?

I tried without success:

```
 val r = (Compile / fastOptJS::webpack).value
```

and

```
 val r = (Compile / (fastOptJS::webpack)).value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task `fastOptJS::webpack` actually refers to the task `webpack` scoped within `fastOptJS`, so the `::` is an actual separator, which you would translate to another `/` in the `build.sbt`, as follows:

```scala
val r = (Compile / fastOptJS / webpack).value
```